# Track the user on the site

Tags: asp.net, http

I want to track the user on site with HTTP session.
Means a single visit is considered as a single HTTP session.

we need this so that multiple entries are not added in table while user navigate through some pages.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Reference this link > http://imar.spaanjaars.com/223/howto-create-a-hit-counter-using-the-globalasax-file-in-aspnet-1x

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `form-authentication` then you can use `global` method `session_start`
Here is a link which may help you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx